# Can't find Silverlight Business Application template

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I originally had `VS 2013 ultimate, Entity Framework 4.1, Silverlight 5 SDK and tools and SQL server 2008` but still when I was going to create a Silverlight project I couldn't find Silverlight Business Application template. Then I did some research and looks like Microsoft has took it out of VS2012+.
So Ok I installed `VS 2010 Ultimate` and still can't find Silverlight Business Application template.
I also make sure to pick `.NET Framework 4.0`  but still no luck.
What things have you installed and what versions that it does show for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 2010 make sure you have the WCF RIA services and .net 4.0 as your target framework and voila, you should have your template.

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: WCF RIA services is a separate install?

Comment: yes sir, you can find it over on [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=wcf%20ria%20services%20download&ac=3)